# Check if we can turn a string into a palindrome by reversing a substring

Tags: algorithms, contest-math, palindrome

Given a string consisting of lower-case characters from English alphabets, we want to reverse a substring from the string such that the string becomes a palindrome.

**Note :** A Palindrome is a string which equals its reverse.

We need to tell if some substring exists which could be reversed to convert the string into palindrome.

**Example** : Let string be "zakdakdz". Then the answer for this string is "yes", since we can reverse the string between indexes 4 and 6 to get zakddkaz

**Basic Approach :** Try to reverse each and every substring and check if we get palindrome or not. However, this is bad approach for a long string.

So is there a better way to solve it ?

Comment: This is a question from a contest which is on-going (at the time of this comment): http://www.codechef.com/TCFS15P/problems/PALINREV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick heuristic:** For very large strings, we can count the frequency of all letters ("a", "b", ...) to quickly weed out strings that cannot possibly be turned into a palindrome.

Let $n$ be the length of the string $S$.

If $n$ is even, then each letter must occur an even number of times. If $n$ is odd, then the same is true except for exactly one letter.

**Search for solutions:** Let $S_i$ be the i-th letter of $S$ and $S_{a:b}$ the substring from (inclusive) index $a$ to $b$.

Checking a substring $S_{a:b}$:

- Is $S_a = S_b$? If yes, check $S_{a+1:b-1}$ instead.

  - Special case: If this substring has a length of 0 or 1, then $S$ is already a palindrome.
- Search for all $S_a$ and $S_b$ in $S_{a+1:b-1}$. If there are none, return false.
- Foreach $S_a \in S_{a+1:b-1}$ at index $i$:

  - Reverse the substring $S_{i:b}$.
  - Is $S$ now a palindrome? If yes, return true.
- Foreach $S_b \in S_{a+1:b-1}$ at index $j$:

  - Reverse the substring $S_{a:j}$.
  - Is $S$ now a palindrome? If yes, return true.
- Return false.

Now apply the substring algorithm to $S$ as $S_{1:n}$.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can ignore the outer characters which match
2. If there is a solution, any successful switch will involve one end apart from the ignored outer characters
3. If there is a solution, you know which characters are at each end of a string you must switch: the outer characters apart from the ignored characters

So in your example you can ignore the *z* at each end, leaving *akdakd* to consider.

If there is a solution it involves switching a string at one end of this which starts with *a* and ends with *d*: in this example there are two possibilities, namely the first *akd* or the last *akd*.

In this example they both work giving final results of *zdkaakdz* or *zakddkaz* respectively.

Comment: If their are multiple possiblities then can we just reverse any substring ?

Comment: Suppose you had *cddcdcdcdddcdddcddc*.  You can ignore the ends of *cddcd* and *dcddc* leaving *cdcdddcdd*.  Looking at the first and last character of this, you know a successful string to reverse starts with *c* and ends with *d*, meaning on the left *cd*, *cdcd*, *cdcdd*, *cdcdd*, *cdcddd* or *cdcdddcd*, and on the right *cdd* or *cdddcdd*.  Most of these do not work, but at least two do.

Comment: Can you provide complexity of your algorithm ?

Comment: I think checking for each substring ending with letter "A" and ending with letter "B" will result in O(N^3) solution if am not wrong

Comment: That looks too high to me, as you only need substrings ending with letter "A" and ending with letter "B" at the ends after ignoring outer characters (any middle ones are irrelevant): there are at most $O(N)$ of these.  Then it is down to how fast you can reverse a substring (best if you keep a single reversal of the original string in memory for this) and how fast you can compare two strings to see if they are the same.